# Realtime input value make auto percentage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to make the input value will show auto percentage value. If I type any input value that will show an auto-generate percentage. Is it an appropriate way to solution? But I do not confirm it's right or wrong.

```js
var on_input_value = parseFloat($("input#input_value").val());
var percentage_value = (on_input_value/100).toFixed(2);
$('#oninput_value_make_auto_percentage').text('£' + percentage_value);
$('input#input_value').keyup(function(){ 
    var on_input_value = parseFloat($("input#input_value").val());
    var percentage_value = (on_input_value/100).toFixed(2);
    $('#oninput_value_make_auto_percentage').text('£' + percentage_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input_value" value="12">%  = 

<span id="oninput_value_make_auto_percentage"></span>
```

Comment: so what is your question??

Comment: My question is,  is it correct or not? @Amir Ahmed